# Are requests for suggestions for improvement of specific real project architectures appropriate?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation, scope

This kind of question seems to straddle this site and programmers, since it doesn't really have one correct answer, but does involve specific and ephemeral technologies.  Also, though it doesn't have one correct answer, it could easily have a best answer.  So does it belong in stackoverflow, programmers, either, neither?

Please don't say this question belongs on meta-programmers, since I don't have the reputation to access it.

Comment: It would help our diagnosis if you could be a bit more specific about your planned question.

Comment: To add further to John's comment, if you post your question to Programmers, CodeReview, etc. and we/others deem it should be migrated, no worries.  It's always easier to make the call when staring at an actual question.  Selecting an appropriate site to ask a library question in particular can be as much about the wording of the question as it is about the target architecture, anticipated users, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based off what I can tell of your question (e.g. no actual code, no concrete prove-able answer AFAICT) I would suggest asking on Programmers.

Answer (score 6):

As the Stack Exchange sites are question and answer, they are not designed for discussion.  Users may point you to the Meta sites when considering this, but I suspect it's more than just the generality of your intent which would be rejected:

`How could .Net Framework 4.0 be improved?`.................................................**Too General**

`How could the Managed Execution Process in .Net 4.0 be improved?`...**Too General**

`How could MSIL conversion for Eiffel {.Net 4.0} be improved?`...........**Not Constructive**

If you ask about specific issues:

`How do I generate MSIL from this Eiffel code, I keep getting error: X??`

Then you are closer to *an answerable* question.

Comment: Note, you might simply browse the common errors/warnings/bugs/user headaches which are already 'discussed' on SE for the architecture of your choice as sign-posts for user requested improvements.

Comment: I'm not talking about anything nearly as general as your "too general" examples.  More like saying what open source libraries a project I'm working on is using and how I plan to put them together, and asking for any suggestions on either what to use or how to put it together.  More like an architecture/design review.  Which I know I would find really interesting to read about if other people asked such questions and had such discussions - if they were talking about their own real projects and not just nit picking .NET 4.0 to death or some such.

Comment: In that case, Programmers seems reasonable, or perhaps if you have concrete (or nearly so) coding examples I'd recommend [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).  For example, someone was asking about [an RPC library](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1811/any-suggestions-about-my-small-rpc-library-design)

Comment: Looking at Code Review it's more appropriate than I first thought. Though I'm looking to get answers BEFORE I have actual code to post, rather than writing it twice, so I really need DesignReview (or something like that), but I guess I might try CodeReview once I get farther along. – psr 7 mins ago